# Ionic App has bad performance and is slow

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic3 App with Angular and i know it is not a native App like pure Android or Swift. But the performance is very poor. I have only a blank projekt but if i start it, I got a black screen for 1-2 seconds and a splash/white screen for 5-8 seconds.

I tried to add lazy loading to the pages and components but it is bad too. If you click on a Tab it will freeze for 1 seconds until the lazy loaded page will be open.

Is this normal? Can I reduce the loading time?

Comment: Are you testing it on an emulator ?

Comment: no on a real device with and build --prof

Comment: What is ionic and APK version your are using to build apk?

Answer (score 3):

First of all the boot time will/should be better with Ionic v4 because their will use web components

Secondly, about your build time, if you want to improve it the first out of box thing to do is to perform your build with `--prod` in order to tells `ionic-app-scripts` to apply methods (like minification) to your code in order to reduce the bundle size (smaller bundle size = faster boot)

```
ionic cordova build ios/android --prod
```

also you should check your `config.xml` to see what are the parameters of your Cordova splashscreen. ensure that you didn't set a long delay which gave you the feeling that the app takes time to boot where actually the app is loaded behind the splash screen

finally there is also work to do on your side because like I said above, the bundle size matter. but it's also about fonts, images etc. less the better. for example you could check your code to find out what you really use and also go thru your libs to be sure that you only include what you need (for example, if you use rxjs, only import lettable operators and not the all lib). If interested I compiled some inputs in that post on the Ionic forum regarding this subject https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/app-boot-time-current-state-and-best-practices

p.s.: Ionic v3 performance are good and boot time could be acceptable/good. My app is approx. 40 pages, 60 components, too much plugins etc. boots in 2.5 seconds on an iPhone 6s

Comment: and on an android phone? ;) my experience is that an iphone is very quick and an android phone very slow

Comment: just tested, same app, 3.8s boot time on my Nexus 5X, a bit slower but still fine for me

Comment: Have you tried out v4 yet? My app has very slow initial page load time, I'm hoping this has been improved in v4

Comment: My app after optimization was already good in v3 so I didn't saw that huge difference. I read that it was better or last time I exchanged on the subject at least a bit better, it also feels a bit better with my app. but don't except to jump for example from 10sec to 0.1sec but I think that it feels at least a bit better out of the box ;)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with your preferences as well. Please try change them in your config as follows.

```
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

In app.component.ts

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.

  // statusBar.styleDefault();
  statusBar.styleLightContent();
  statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('B27F16');

  setTimeout(() => {
    splashScreen.hide();
  }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Please refrain from adding "hope this helps" and other such material to answers. It's not the kind of technical writing we prefer here, and anyway, surely nobody posts something hoping it does not help.